# Finding palindrome count

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, palindrome

Given two number 0140 ,9802
I have to find all palindrome between them .
Please suggest optimal algo if there is any to salve this .Thanks

These number will increase like 0141,0142,...0220(its palindrome ),..till 9802

I tried one below

```
public static void calc(String s1,String s2){
    int count=0;
    int s=Integer.parseInt(s1);
    int e=Integer.parseInt(s2);
    for(int i=s;i<=e;i++){
        if(i<1000){
            if(i%10==0){
                i=i/10;
                if(i%10==i/10){
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }else{
            if(isPalindrome(i)){
                count ++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
    int palindrome = number; // copied number into variable
    int reverse = 0;
    while (palindrome != 0) {
        int remainder = palindrome % 10;
        reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
        palindrome = palindrome / 10;
    }
    if (number == reverse) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com as it's about optimizing working code.

Comment: How large can the values of these numbers be?

Comment: If `0140` is a number, is `0220` a palindrome number? (Because `220` isn't.)

Comment: @biziclop yes here 0220 is palindrome

Comment: Are these numbers always of the same length?

Comment: @kraskevich yes always 4

Comment: By the way, is there any problem with your current solution? Is it wrong? Is it too slow?

Comment: @kraskevich too slow

Comment: Too slow for what? You should really give more details about the input data (how many pairs of lower and upper bound it should handle, for instance) and the expected performance to get a meaningful answer.